# Two regulators driven from same source

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a single +12V input, and am creating two separate +5V supply lines from it.  Using the datasheet and TI WebBench, I chose values for the input capacitors.  However, with two regulators, all the input capacitors are essentially in parallel.

Example:

[image: Schematic]

My question is:  Do I need to consider any changes to the input capacitors?  Or, would it be typical to put diodes in front of each regulator input (before the caps) ?

Comment: You don't need diodes, and I'd suggest that you only need a 100 nF capacitor close to each IC and 20 uF total for the power bus. If you have long (or thin) traces for the the power around your PCB you could place the recommended 10 uF and 100 nF close to each regulator IC.

Comment: Depending on source trace inductance, ESR of input caps and peak currents,  there is a chance of crosstalk aliasing with difference frequency noise on input, but no worse than DC source % regulation error.

Comment: @JackCreasey 100nF input cap for 5A buck regulator at 250kHz? Are you sure? I would increase 10uF capacitor to 22 or more and place inductor in series with the input current to make an LC filter for each buck regulator input. Otherwise the stress for the capacitors of the previous stage will be huge and these large pulsed currents can make significant EMI.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov If TI Webench recommended those values, then they are likely enough don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Putting diodes in series with the feed lines is adding loss and partially defeating the objectives of using switching regulators. If you look on page 15 (and onwards) of the LM2678 data sheet they tell you the capacitors they recommend and, if you look on page 19 and 22 they imply that the input capacitor should be located as close to the input pin as possible: -

[image]

This is to reduce (as much as possible) high frequency switching currents from flowing through the traces that feed the converters. Treat each converter as an island.